# отделение ссылки от текста

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть запрос например:
*открыть страницу [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com)*
Как можно отсеять саму ссылку от остального текста

Comment: Ссылка всегда начинается с `www`?

Comment: @dIm0n нет не всегда

Comment: @dIm0n но если есть идея как реализовать через www чтобы она всегда была то излагайте 
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Вот так вот:

```
from urlextract import URLExtract

print(URLExtract().find_urls('открыть страницу www.youtube.com'))
```

Регулярка будет большая и сложная, если хотите поддерживать любой формат ссылок, так что имеет смысл поставить пакет `urlextract`.